# Regular expression to get a word at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following two strings:

```
http://test1/foo
http://test2/foo_bar
```

I want to get foo in the first example, but not in the second example; in other words just the foo as is not if we append something to it

I tried the following regular expression:

> /foo[^.]/g

but it is catching both "foo"

Thanks

Comment: `/foo$/g` should suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an anchor for the end of a string `$` - `/foo$/g`.